# Toggle key to start and pause program

Tags: java, loops

I've got a program, in java, that is just a simple autoclicker. What I'm looking to do is make it so that with the press of a key (say, F9) the infinite loop in the program runs without interruption - and when another key (say, F10) is pressed, the program pauses, such that once I press F9 again the program resumes. Here's the code that I've got:

```
package SimpleCode;
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

public class AutoClicker {

 public static void MainFunction(){
  while(true){
   leftClick();
   delay(6.5);
  }
 }

 protected static void delay(double seconds){
  createMacro();
  macro.delay((int(seconds * 1000.0));
 }

 protected static void leftClick(){
  createMacro();
  macro.mousePress(MouseEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
  macro.mouseRelease(MouseEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
 }

 private static Robot macro = null;

 private static void createMacro(){
  try {
   macro = new Robot();
  } catch (AWTException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
 }

 public static void main(String args[]){
  MainFunction();
 }

}﻿
```

I suppose to interrupt the loop, I must find a way to make the "while(true)" part false once F10 is pressed, but that's all that I can reason. I'm not sure how pressing F9 would start the program.

Note: credits to SimpleCode's youtube video on the subject for the above framework.

Comment: Right tool for the job: Unless Java is a requirement here, for UI automation I recommend [AutoHotKey](https://autohotkey.com/) where such actions are achieved with lower effort and [minimum of code](https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/64576-the-definitive-autofire-thread/?p=407264) (scroll to snippet called *The Toggle*).

Comment: Oh ok, I'll definitely look into that - java wasn't a requirement here, it's just  that I"m moderately comfortable with it

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want to do something like

```
private boolean running;

private void onPressf9Action(){
running = true;
}

while(running) {
//perform action
}

private void someOtherAction(){
running = false;
}
```